# Installing on Macbook 2007 crashing

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, macbook

I am trying to install the latest Ubuntu OS (16.04) on my old macbook 2007. The installer works fine until I get an error that says it is unable to install GRUB in `/dev/sda`. The guide I am following says to choose the option to `"continue without the boot loader"`, however the installer either freezes or crashes when I press okay. I am using a USB to install and am following this [guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266424) .
Please help? I'd like to be able to use this laptop for school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to try installing an older version of Ubuntu and then using the Software Updater to upgrade to 16.04.